# Kotlin: Make a single selection RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view that is capable of multiple selections whose adapter looks like this. The item has a checkbox Radio button followed by some other elements

```
class SchoolLabelAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SchoolLabelAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var institutionLabelListItem: List<InstitutionLabelItem> = arrayListOf()

class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemSchoolLabelBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        var schoolLabelListItem: List<schoolLabelItem> = arrayListOf()
        fun bind(
                schoolLabelItemData: SchoolLabelItem,
                itemIdentifier: String?
        ) {
            binding........
            binding.schoolIsSelected.tag = itemIdentifier
            binding.schoolIsSelected.isChecked = schoolLabelItemData.isSelected
            binding.schoolIsSelected.setOnClickListener {
                (it as CheckBox).isChecked = institutionLabelItemData.isSelected
            }
        }
    }

fun initList(list: List<SchoolLabelAdapter>) {
        this.schoolLabelListItem = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return InstitutionLabelAdapter.ViewHolder(
                DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                        layoutInflater, R.layout.item_school_label, parent, false
                )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() =
            schoolLabelListItem.size


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SchoolLabelAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val schoolItemData = schoolLabelListItem[position]
        holder.bind(schoolItemData, schoolItemData.id)
    }
```

What's happening here is that we just init the `isChecked` of all the boxes to false before onClick and then set the `isSelected` to true for the item when `onClick` sets the `isChecked` to true.

SchoolLabelItem class

```
data class SchoolLabelItem(
    val id: String,
    ...
    var isSelected: Boolean = false
)
```

I tried setting only the selected `item.isSelected` to true but multiple checkboxes still get selected.

```
 binding.schoolIsSelected.setOnClickListener {
                for(item in schoolLabelListItem)
                {
                    if(adapterPosition== Integer.parseInt(item.id))
                    {
                        logd("display1","item selected $adapterPosition")
                        item.isSelected = true
                        (it as CheckBox).isChecked = item.isSelected
                    }
                    else {
                        item.isSelected = false
                        (it as CheckBox).isChecked = item.isSelected
                    }
                }
                //(it as CheckBox).isChecked = schoolLabelItemData.isSelected
            }
```

I tried printing a log statement inside the if condition but that didn't print too
Please provide a better way or let me know if there is any mistake that I'm making in this approach.

Comment: so is none of the checkboxes selected or are multiple selected?

Comment: multiple selected on clicking with the loop

Comment: notify adapter after add /remove or update list ( isSelected status) call this after update **notifyDataSetChanged()**

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() unresolved inside the viewHolder class

Comment: can you attach your adapter class, I will do the new changes.

Comment: 1) remove your code from bind function and put in binViewHolder.

2) make an interface of ClickInterface and manage from activity or adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In your list adapter class hold last selected checked position and in your ViewHolder pass that `lastSelectedPosition` with `currentPosition`. And then implement like:

```
 binding.schoolIsSelected.isChecked = lastSelectedPosition == currentPosition
```

And create one interface add pass onClickedPosition. Implement this interface in your adapter and get the selected position and replace it with `lastSelectedPosition`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a Flag variable in the view holder. The flag variable will be storing the last position of the selected item.

> val isLastSelectedPos = -1

```
class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemSchoolLabelBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    
    var isLastSelectedPos = -1

    var schoolLabelListItem: List<schoolLabelItem> = arrayListOf()
    fun bind(
            schoolLabelItemData: SchoolLabelItem,
            itemIdentifier: String?
    ) {
        binding........
        binding.schoolIsSelected.tag = itemIdentifier
        binding.schoolIsSelected.isChecked = schoolLabelItemData.isSelected
        binding.schoolIsSelected.setOnClickListener {
            (it as CheckBox).isChecked = institutionLabelItemData.isSelected
        }
    }
}
```

OnclickListener, if isLastSelectedPos == -1 , then store adapter position in isLastSelectedPos and update model class. else remove model.ischeck at isLastSelectedPos position and then update with lates adapter position.

```
binding.schoolIsSelected.setOnClickListener {
            if(isLastSelectedPos == -1){
              isLastSelectedPos = holder.adapterposition
              schoolLabelListItem[holder.adapterposition].isSelected = true
              notifyDataSetChanged()
            }else{
              schoolLabelListItem[isLastSelectedPos].isSelected = false
              schoolLabelListItem[holder.adapterposition].isSelected = true
              isLastSelectedPos = holder.adapterposition
              notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged unresolved inside the viewHolder class

Comment: can you attach your adapter class, I will do the new changes.

Comment: added the class take a look